# Facade pattern - return original object or modified original object

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have e.g. object like this:

```
Original obj = new Original();
```

And I use from this object e.g. method like(this object has many methods and fields):
obj.getMeYourName();

And I would like to have similar object which is almost same but some methods return something else. I want to solve it by facade.

So, at first I want to create facade and decided if I would return direct object or modified.
What is the best way?

Something like this: ?

```
Original obj = new Original(); 

OriginalFacade obj = new OriginalFacade(Original obj, boolean getDirectObject);


OriginalFacade(Original obj, boolean getDirectObject) {
if (getDirectObject) {
    return obj //How to convert object into OriginalFacade type?
} else {
   obj.setMeYourName("Something else"); 
   return obj; //Howto convert object into OriginalFacade type?
}
}
```

So, I have 2 problems:

1, is it good solution choose original object or modified original object thru constructor with e.g. boolean getDirectObject?

2, **how to easy return original object which must me mapped into OriginalFacade Object** 
     Must I have implement all methods from original object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, the facade pattern uses a common interface that is used by clients.

For instance:

```
public interface Facade {
    public String getMeYourName();
    public void someOtherMethod();
}

public class Original implements Facade {
    private String name;

    Original(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getMeYourName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void someOtherMethod() {
        // a lot of great code
    }
}

public class Modified implements Facade {
    private Facade original;
    private String otherName;

    Modified(Facade original, String otherName) {
        this.original = original;
        this.otherName = otherName;
    }

    public String getMeYourName() {
        return otherName;
    }

    public void someOtherMethod() {
        original.someOtherMethod();
    }
}
```

The clients should only need to see the Facade interface, and shouldn't need to care which actual implementation they are dealing with.

Answer (score 1):

Your code demonstrates you have not understood `Facade` at all.
In first place `Facade` should be used to provide a simple interface to complex algorithms.

Second, the facade pattern allows you to access its composed objects, for example:

```
public class OriginalFacade{
  public Original original;
}
```

Unless you follow the [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter), this code is perfect valid.
Regardless, if Facade is used, you should not need to access those objects.

The following link explains a little bit of [Facade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) 
I recommend you buy and read this [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000SEIBB8)

Answer (score 1):

Facade is not the patter to be used here. It is used to make a complex interface simpler, for example, making out-of-the-box usage patterns.

In your case, why don't you just extend the Original class and overload the methods you want to behave differently?